# Where does the idea of mentioning that they're in a manga come from?

Tags: tropes

I was reading Recipe for Gertrude, and in chapter 10, there's a part where they're driving in a car and one of the characters says, "Now sit down please. That could be fatal in this manga." I was wondering if this was a relatively common occurrence. Also, I was wondering where that idea of mentioning in a manga that they're in a manga came from.

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed a common trope, and not even a Manga specific one, generally referred to as [Breaking the Fourth Wall](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BreakingTheFourthWall).

For example the Marvel character Deadpool is a well-known for doing this in an even more extreme fashion. You can find a lot of Manga/Anime examples [here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/BreakingTheFourthWall/AnimeAndManga).

To learn more about the different versions of Fourth Wall Breakage visit this article on the [Sliding Scale of Fourth Wall Hardness](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SlidingScaleOfFourthWallHardness).

To my knowledge, in this case it would count as [Fourth Wall Observer](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FourthWallObserver).